# Get selected option number Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As we know select list can have many options but each option have one number of option and them start from [0] for example:

```
[0]<option>E.U</option>
[1]<option>India</option>
[2]<option>Peru</option>
```

I have a select using angular so and **Ajax call** like

```
function cargarCatalogo() {
    apiService.get("../../api/Catalogos/", null,
    function (res) {
        $scope.Catalogos = res.data;
        $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];

        //select inicial value 
        $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
    }, errorCatalogo);
}
```

**View:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-init="Catalogos[0]" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"></select>
```

As you can see there I have `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];`, so for default I have `<option>E.U</option>` as default option.

What I want to do is to get this selected value or whatever other value it can be 1,2,3 and send via a parameter to another controller with `$state.go` like:

```
function edit() {
    ($("#tabla_catalogos tr.selected").hasClass("selected"));
    {
        var table = $('#tabla_catalogos').DataTable();
        var row = table.rows('.selected').data();
        var id = table.cell(row[0], 1).data();

        $state.go("root.detalleregistros", { codigo: row[0].Codigo, nombre: row[0].Nombre});

    }
```

As you can see I send parameters there, but there are from my database, and I don´t want to get this value from a parameter, I want to get from actual selected value. How can I achieve it? Regards

Update: I try sachila ranawaka comment but I don't receive 0,1,2 value I receive an object like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood the question but if you want to get the selected value then you can get it from the `ng-model`. Then pass the parameter as URL param to state.

```
 $state.go("root.detalleregistros", { codigo: $scope.selected);
```

Comment: But it don´t return me value [0] for example it returns all my object

Comment: can you post what it returns

Comment: Yes, there is in my question

Comment: then use `$scope.selected.Catalogopadreid`

Comment: Yes I try it but it always return 0, I think thats not my selected option, `CatalogoPadreId` comes from my db, so `$scope.selected` get info from my db but I just want to get actual selected value

Comment: For be more clearly I want index of selected option so my index should be 1 or 2